# Connecting Ros on a chroot with AMD ATI display

Tags: xorg, amd-graphics, chroot, ros

So, I have ROS Indigo on a chroot on my Ubuntu 15.10. 
I installed the nao-gazebo package to simulate a Nao robot using Gazebo. It was working fine. I used the command `xhost +local:` on the host and in the chroot I use `export DISPLAY=:0`.
Until one day I went to "Additional Drivers" software on my Ubuntu and decided to upgrade the display driver from the Generic "X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from x-server-xorg-video-ati" to "Video Driver for the AMD graphics accelerator fglrx (proprietary)" to get better video display on Ubuntu.

When I did this and tried to run gazebo on the chroot, It cannot run and it always fails with the error:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

And I cannot run it properly until I go back to "Additional Drivers" and switch back to the old X.Org driver. 
Is there a way that I can keep the proprietary video driver and somehow let the chroot environment deal with it?